# Designing a hypothesis experiment for cost reduction

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, treatment-effect

I have two groups of samples.
Control group and treatment group, treatment group gets a special training.
This training will cost me $X$ dollars per person. This training is supposedly reduce the problems/cost of the trainees down the line. Will evaluate the cost at different periods of time (3 month, 1 year ect.)

Would the following be a valid test? The goal is to minimize cost.

$H_0$: $M_0 = M_1 + X$ ($M_0$ is mean cost of control, $M_1$ for treatment)

$H_A$: $M_0 > M_1 + X$

I wasn't sure if we can add fixed value like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a statistical point of view, the test you propose makes sense: it is absolutely fine to add a constant as you suggest.

From an economic point of view, the cost-benefit analysis will make sense if you compare the immediate cost $X$ to the present discounted sum of cost flows in the future. If $m_0(t)$ and $m_1(t)$ denote the costs during week $t$ (for instance) for individuals from the control and treatment groups, the program will generate no gains iff:
$$
\sum_{t=0}^\infty \beta^t m_0(t) = \sum_{t=0}^\infty \beta^t m_1(t) + X
$$
where $t=0$ is the beginning of the training (which is also when $X$ is paid) and $\beta$ is the discount rate.

In practice, it is of course difficult to keep measuring $m_0$ and $m_1$ until $t\rightarrow \infty$, but you can try to proxy these quantities with the data you have.